# Postfix Relay: Only send messages outbound to Internet on certain criterion, relay to another relay if criterion not met

Tags: postfix, email-server

This will sound a little bit convoluted and complex, but we have a *very* evil setup currently for email at one of my clients' environments.

From the innermost system to the outside we have:

```
Exchange Server -> Sendmail Server -> McAfee Email Gateway -> OUTSIDE
```

This is a little evil because external-destination Out of Office emails (from someone inside the system to outside) don't work, they are seemingly caught at the McAfee Email Gateway and aren't relayed outside.

What I'm trying to do is set up a Postfix server as a relay AND an SMTP server, and depending on what's being received either:

1. Send email out directly (using SMTP, for Out of Office replies only)
2. Relay mail to the Sendmail server, for the rest of its relaying duties as would normally have happened.

This would then look a little like the following:

```
Exchange Server -> Postfix Relay --- Out of Office messages only ---> OUTSIDE
                         |
                   All other mail
                         |
                         ---> Sendmail Server/Relay ---> McAfee Email Gateway ---> OUTSIDE
```

I'm a little hung up on how to configure Postfix for the selective relaying option.  Is there anyone who can give some insight on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a very hackish approach to this.

Essentially, I put a customized SMTP 'server' written in Python running between the Postfix server and the Exchange server that actually handles the *real* relay routing.  It's written in Python, and runs as superuser on port 25 (because port binding restrictions).

That Python script then processes the message as one normally would, running through an email from string parser, and then reading the subject line to determine where to send it, and then sending the original message, unaltered, to either the local Postfix SMTP server (to be sent straight outbound), or to the other relay on the network.  So far, it *seems* to be working.

This is the code I use for this at the Python side of things:

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Libraries
import smtplib
import smtpd
import asyncore
import email
import sys
from datetime import datetime

print('Starting custom mail handling server...')

# CONFIGURATION VARIABLES - We are expecting to relay, so... let's relay.
SMTP_RELAY = 'SMTP_RELAY_HOSTNAME_OR_IP'
SMTP_DIRECT = 'localhost'

#############
#############
# SMTP SERVER
#############
#############


# noinspection PyMissingTypeHints,PyBroadException
class AutoReplyHandlerSMTP(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data, **kwargs):
        print('MESSAGE RECEIVED - [%s]' % datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        print('Receiving message from:', peer)
        print('Message addressed from:', mailfrom)
        print('Message addressed to  :', rcpttos)
        print('Message length        :', len(data))
        print(data)

        # Flush the output buffered (handy with the nohup launch)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # Analyze and extract data headers
        msg = email.message_from_string(data)
        subject = ''
        try:
            subject = msg['Subject']
            subject = subject.lower()
        except:
            print("Subject error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print('Message subject       :', msg['Subject'])

        # Determine whether we are directly sending outbound, or if we're relaying to another server.
        if "automatic reply" in subject:
            print("Automatic reply received, sending directly.")
            # Local postfix SMTPd is on tcp/6625.
            conn = smtplib.SMTP(host=SMTP_DIRECT, port=6625, timeout=60)
            conn.sendmail(mailfrom, rcpttos, msg.as_string())
            conn.quit()
        else:
            print("Standard message detected, sending to relay.")
            # Other relay server is on tcp/25 (standard smtp)
            conn = smtplib.SMTP(host=SMTP_RELAY, timeout=60)
            conn.sendmail(mailfrom, rcpttos, msg.as_string())

        # Flush the output buffered (handy with the nohup launch)
        print("\n\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        return


# Listen to port 25 ( 0.0.0.0 can be replaced by the ip of your server but that will work with 0.0.0.0 )
server = AutoReplyHandlerSMTP(('0.0.0.0', 25), None)

# Wait for incoming emails
asyncore.loop()
```

I configured Postfix to listen on SMTP on a different port.  In effect, this is what ended up being done, in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` on my Ubuntu server for this, and is ultimately the two lines and how I configured SMTPd in Postfix - note that you can use any high numbered port for any other port for Postfix SMTPd, but I chose something easy:

```
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
6625      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

The Python script then forwards the data over to port `6625`, and Postfix's SMTPd running there; with that being done, we specifically let Python determine which SMTP server or relay is the "next hop".  This kinda breaks the standard "Received by" headers, but it supposedly works fine with messages.

I haven't run into any issues with my solution, and it *seems* to be working.  Additional tests are necessary, but this 'solution' seems to solve the routing issue for how to route messages (direct SMTP out, or through the rest of the relays) without messing with Postfix configuration really.